# Strange jmp vs call behavior

Tags: assembly, x86

At the address of some function I write a `jmp` to another location(let's call it `Z`).

I have a function `void f(int x, int y)`

At `Z` the first instruction is a `jmp` to `f`. That way it all works, all arguments are received in `f` correctly.
But, if I change `jmp` to `call`, the second argument receives the value of the first argument, and the first argument receives garbage. Yet if [at `Z`]  before `call` to `f` I also push a couple of values, these values are received correctly.

So what's going on?

Comment: `call` puts a return address on the stack. The same stack is used to pass parameters.

Comment: @ecm, thanks. Solved by `push [esp+8]; push [esp+8]` before `call`. This is embarrassing, I should actually learn assembly and the architecture.

Comment: You're going to make mistakes while learning, that's normal.  To avoid embarrassment, use a debugger to single-step and watch what's going on (changes in register values after each instruction will be highlighted by a good debugger), so you can figure out where your ideas didn't match reality on your own.

Comment: You could also use a register-based calling convention (which is the default on any reasonably non-obsolete ISA today), though you may end up surprised again once you have too many arguments. On the other hand, you'll likely be even *more* surprised once you get to a RISC-like processor that *doesn't* push the return address on a `call`.